# ORA-01034: ORACLE not available ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle11g

I am running Oracle 11g on Linux server and one the below Database issues occurred suddenly (every 2 weeks or 3 weeks sometimes):

Some times: 
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available ORA-27102: out of memory Linux-x86_64 Error: 12: Cannot allocate memory Additional information: 1 Additional information: 163844 Additional information: 8

And last time: 
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory

When I tried to startup database after setting up SID but I had the below error: 
SQL> startup
ORA-00845: MEMORY_TARGET not supported on this system

I rebooted the server then everything is OK

My page size: 4096
kernel.shmall = 4294967296

How can I prevent these issues from happening again? should I update anything in Oracle memory settings?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your /dev/shm allocation is greater than what you have set for MEMORY_MAX_TARGET

Example fix for a memory allocation of 4Gb:

```
mount -o remount,size=4096m /dev/shm
```

Entry for /etc/fstab file to make the change permanent

```
tmpfs    /dev/shm   tmpfs   size=4096m  0 0
```

Also see Oracle support: Doc ID 1399209.1 - ORA-00845 - Which value for /dev/shm is needed to startup database without ORA-00845

Answer (score 0):

See, this is what worked for me. My ORACLE_SID, ORACLE_HOME etc., were just fine.

1. Restart the listener - lsnrctl start
2. sqlplus /nolog
3. connect /as sysdba
4. startup